# How to fix Cannot find module 'redux'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

In a tsx file I get the error Cannot find module 'redux'. I have installed "redux": "^4.0.5" and "@types/redux": "3.6.31". I have added the option "moduleResolution": "node" in tsconfig.json. Please help me to resolve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried to refresh your IDE?

Comment: Have you tried this?

need to install react-redux but also redux library.
npm install --save redux

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I have installed react-redux and redux.

Comment: The problem is not relative to refresh IDE but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. delete the **node_modules** folder
2. reinstall all the modules written in **package.json** by typing `npm install`
3. restart the IDE (VS-code or whatever you are using )

if till you find the same problem.

install **redux** and  **react-redux** again.

`npm install --save redux react-redux`

Comment: I have resolved this problem by your way. Thank you very much!

Comment: but alas, I got a downvote for answering .. if my answer helped you, will appreciate an upvote for the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install react-redux but also redux library.

```
npm install --save redux
```

Comment: There is the line `"redux": "^4.0.5"` in dependencies of package.json.